# Matrix/Tensor Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $B$ is an $n \times k$ matrix.  Let $C$ be a tensor, where
$$C(i,j,k) = A(i,j) + B(j,k)$$
What is a suitable (tensor) algebraic operation that summarizes this computation? (i.e makes possible to write this without using indices?)

Comment: An operation with matrix input and tensor output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard notation for this kind of operation.

You could write something like

> $C = A + B$ where $A$ and $B$ are extended by the natural projections $\mathbb R^{m + n + k} \to \mathbb R^{m + n}$ and $\mathbb R^{m + n + k} \to \mathbb R^{n + k}$.

If you want to be able to write this purely symbolically I would probably name those projections $\pi, \sigma$ and write $C=A\pi + B \sigma$. The way you formalise and notate this operation depends most on how you're interpreting the tensors - here I'm viewing them as totally contravariant, i.e. as multilinear maps $\mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$.

To be honest the index notation seems by far the neatest way to write this down.

Answer (score 2):

How about $$\mathbf{C = Ae + eB}$$
where $\mathbf{e}$ is the vectors of all ones?

And $\mathbf{Ae}$ represents the dyadic (aka tensor) product.

Comment: At least in Matlab, the result of tensor product of two matrices is a matrix. I am looking for an operation that gives me a tensor.